# How do i save the custome list in Room Db in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

My model Class

```
@Entity(tableName = "Custome Tasks")
data class CustomeTask(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long =  0,
    @NonNull
    val title: String,
    @NonNull
    @TypeConverters(DataConverter::class)
    val tasks: List<Task>
)
```

Task data class

```
data class Task(
    val title : String ,
    val time : Int
)
```

Notice : i have one String and Int in Task Class. i think this is challenge .
And i have used this typconverter by searching google

```
class DataConverter {


    @TypeConverter 
    fun fromOptionValuesList(tasks: 
       List<CustomeTask>?): String? {
        if (tasks == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object :
            TypeToken<List<CustomeTask>?>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(tasks, type)
    }

  @TypeConverter 
    fun toOptionValuesList(tasks: String?): List<CustomeTask>? {
        if (tasks == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object :
            TypeToken<List<CustomeTask>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(tasks, type)
  

  }
 }
```

I want to save that list of task in Table .
How can do this.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Your type converter is incorrect.
Convert Task instead of CustomeTask (in TypeConverter)

Comment: yes i have corrected , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you have done is right except the class that you have passed in the DataConverter. You have passed `CustomeTask` class which is the Entity data class instead of the `Task` Class that is supposed to be passed. Simply update the model which is supposed to be converted from `CustomeTask` to `Task` Class in the DataConverter and you will be good to go.

```
class DataConverter {


    @TypeConverter 
    fun fromOptionValuesList(tasks: 
       List<Task>?): String? {
        if (tasks == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object :
            TypeToken<List<Task>?>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(tasks, type)
    }

  @TypeConverter 
    fun toOptionValuesList(tasks: String?): List<Task>? {
        if (tasks == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object :
            TypeToken<List<Task>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(tasks, type)
  

  }
 }
```